# Notation for symmetric closure of a relation

Tags: notation, relations

Given a binary relation $r$, its reflexive closure, $r \cup id$, is sometimes written as $r^?$ or $r^=$. Its transitive closure is written as $r^+$. Its reflexive, transitive closure is written as $r^*$.

What about its symmetric closure, $r \cup r^{-1}$? Is there any existing notation for that? I saw $s(r)$ once, but that's not particularly appealing to me. Are there any other candidates?

Comment: I've never seen one. I don't visit places where I would be likely to, so haven't seen the others either. If you need the concept often in something you are writing, invent notation and tell your reader.

Answer (score 2):

I would use $R^s$ for the symmetrisation of a relation $R$, as in this [link](https://books.google.fr/books?id=5TaoAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT43&lpg=PT43&dq=symmetrization+binary+relation&source=bl&ots=vDQIngxsOP&sig=ACfU3U1MbyS5KaNPB2XcCaiYaa3WnnVD0A&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfqbC0_MDiAhVyyoUKHb4nBfIQ6AEwE3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=symmetrization%20binary%20relation&f=false).

> By symmetrization of the binary relation $R$ on a set one obtains the
>   symmetric relation $R^s$ defined by: $a \mathrel{R^s} b$ if and only
>   if $a \mathrel{R}  b$ or $b \mathrel{R} a$, such that every symmetric
>   relation implying $\mathrel{R}$ also implies $\mathrel{R^s}$.

Zassenhaus, Hans J. The theory of groups. 2nd ed. Chelsea Publishing Company, New York, 1958. 265 pp.

Comment: Thanks! I’m afraid the link doesn’t work for me though. I presume it shows the notation in use in a book. Perhaps you could kindly attach a screenshot instead? Thanks again.

Comment: I have reproduced the relevant paragraph.

Comment: Very kind, thank you